# Table in R when data can contain one or multiple observations

Tags: r, datatable

I have a variable that looks like this:

A, B, A;B, B, C, A;C

At the moment, when I create a table of this (in R) I get the following counts:

A = 1, B = 2, C = 1, A;B = 1, A;C = 1

However, Id like to create a table with counts at this level:

A = 3, B = 3, C = 2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_rows.html to separate your values and then apply `table`.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vector:

```
v<-c("A","B","A","B","B","C","A","C")
```

and want a data.frame with the frequencies for each letter, you can use the function `table()` and put it into a data.frame:

```
freq<-as.data.frame(table(v))

freq
  v Freq
1 A    3
2 B    3
3 C    2
```